# Deserialize json nested object in android

Tags: java, android, json, deserialization

I am in trouble. I can not deserialize this object that I return json from an http request. Can anyone help me? 
I downloaded and added to the libs folder `gson_2.2.4.jar`. 
We insert the object json

```
{
    "returnCode": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "token": "aaaaa =",
            "code": "xx",
            "id": ""
        }
    ],
    "errorMsg": ""
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a class of data object, for example

```
public class DataObj {
    public String token;
    public String code;
    public String id;
}
```

and then create another class for the whole json, for example

```
public class MyObj {
    public int returnCode;
    public DataObj[] data;
    public String errorMsg;
}
```

then create an object of MyObj and use deserializer from GSON to read json, 
for example:

```
GSON gson = new GSON();
MyObj newMyObj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyObj.class);
```

Where jsonString contains the json object as string.

(@Shivam Verma thanks for your edit)